# Transfer data between websites

Tags: c#, .net, api, architecture

I need some architectural advice on how to build a background service application.

**Background:**

I have 2 websites, and I need to transfer some data from website A to website B. Service
would have to run in a background (as windows service) and should connect (every 5 minutes)
to websites's A database directly (MSSQL) grab some data and insert this data through
websites's B API (API is build on MVC Web Api). Both websites are hosted on a same virtual
machine (Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter), but this might change (website B can be switched to another virtual server or cloud hosting as Windows Azure or Amazon AWS).

**Question:**

What do you suggest (best practices) and what guidelines you can give me? I want this to
be scalable and fast as possible and that service will receive multiple requests.

Thank you,
Jani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is important to know what data was transferred, then:

1. Add logs - log4net for instance
2. Issue tickets if the process stops, and close the ticket when it restarts, this way you will know if a process fails. Depending on the amount of data use you could use Redis/Riak.
3. Put monitoring on each service A and B, and you might also consider restarting the service via IIS on fail down.